SplineView listen for even outside the 3d scene (in swift code)
I have added a simple test scene to my UIKit project
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import SplineRuntime

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myContainerView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Create the URL to your Spline scene
        if let sceneURL = URL(string: "https://build.spline.design/mYSceneId/scene.splineswift") {
            
            // Create the SwiftUI-based SplineView
            let splineView = SplineView(sceneFileURL: sceneURL)
           
            
            // Wrap the SplineView inside a UIHostingController
            let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: splineView)
            hostingController.view.backgroundColor = .clear
            
            // Add the hosting controller to the current view controller
            addChild(hostingController)
            
            // Set the frame of the hostingController's view to match the parent view
            hostingController.view.frame = self.myContainerView.bounds
            hostingController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            
            // Add the hosting controller's view to the UIKit view hierarchy
            self.myContainerView.addSubview(hostingController.view)
            
            // Notify the hosting controller that it has been added
            hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)
        }
    }
}

I need to know when some specific object is pressed and trigger some swift code smth similar like for javascript:
isten to events
You can listen to any Spline Event you set in the Events panel of the editor by attaching a listener to the Spline instance.

import { Application } from '@splinetool/runtime';

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas3d');
const spline = new Application(canvas);
spline
    .load('https://prod.spline.design/6Wq1Q7YGyM-iab9i/scene.splinecode')
    .then(() => {
        spline.addEventListener('mouseDown', (e) => {
            if (e.target.name === 'Cube') {
                console.log('I have been clicked!');
            }
        });
    });

